# Is there a reason to use variational inference for point estimates?

Tags: bayesian, variational-bayes, map-estimation

I have seen Bayesian hierarchical models, particularly in computational biology, that use variational inference, but do not use the uncertainty provided by a variational solution. For example, [MOFA](https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-020-02015-1) is a factor analysis model that uses stochastic gradient descent to perform variational inference. However, the authors use only the mean of the variational distribution as a point estimate, and do not consider the uncertainty quantified by posterior variance.

Is there some computational advantage to doing gradient descent on the parameters of the variational distributions for each parameter, rather than doing gradient descent directly on each parameter?

I have assumed that gradient descent to obtain a MAP solution would be faster and simpler than trying to optimise the KL divergence between a variational approximation and the true posterior.

Could it be that variational inference is an easier solution to derive mathematically?

Comment: VI is often used when the true likelihood function is intractable. Without reading the paper itself, I can't say whether this is the reason.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I'd not heard VI used in that circumstance. I'd have thought that only "black box" type of VI would be usable for that purpose? If I remember well, the authors mentioned that they experimented with MCMC so I doubt this is the case.

Comment: From my understanding (and I could be wrong), if you only care about point estimates, you should use other (often simpler) algorithms. E.g., if you're doing inference on something along the lines of a GMM - you should use the EM algorithm if you care about point estimates (cluster means), and VI if you care about the entire posterior.